# Get count of fields with a specific value in a row? mysqli-php

Tags: php, mysqli, count

please assume this as the table
tablename- schemeOverview

```
| slno    |schemename | amount| date2 | date3 | date4 ...daten   |
|---------|-----------|-------|-------|-------|-------|----------|
|    1    | Cell      | 1000  | DUE   | DUE   |       |          |
|    2    | Cell      | 1000  | PAID  | PAID  |       |          | 
|    3    | Cell      | 1000  | DUE   | DUE   | DUE   |          |
|    4    | Cell      | 1000  | PAID  | PAID  |       |          | 
|    5    | Cell      | 1000  | DUE   | DUE   |       |          |
```

I am trying to count the number of fields that have value as 'PAID' .
for example the count of PAID for slno-2 should be 2.

the number of date columns varies per table but I have the count of date columns for a table.So a better option would be to check all fields of the specified row(slno)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of brain drain I came up with this and It works!

```
$paidCount=0;
$sql2 = "SELECT *  FROM " .$scheme_name. " WHERE slno = " .$recBookNo;
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
if($result2)
 {

    while ($row19 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
    {
         foreach ($row19 as $key => $value)
            {
                    if(($value)=='PAID')
                        {
                            $paidCount++;
                        }
            }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
SELECT slno,count(*) AS paid 
FROM schemeOverview
WHERE 'PAID' IN (date2, date3, date4,...,daten)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `count()`

```
SELECT count(date2) as cd2 FROM schemeOverview WHERE date2 = "PAID"
```

This will store the value into cd2, in this case 2

Comment: thats incorrect answer, its not what the user wants.

Comment: I suppose that when the dates collumn variate per table, you could create an second table. Then join the results. Atleast that is what i would have done